# Documentation for c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource class?

Tags: documentation, connection-pooling, c3p0

I need documentation for ComboPooledDataSource class from c3p0 library. The one I find on developer's web site contains only method names, but not a single line of explanation about what each method does. Please, don't tell me this is an old library, that is not developed etc. - I have some quite old code to look at, and I am not able to change the library currently. I need some short explanation at least for the following methods:

```
setConnectionTesterClassName(connectionTesterClassName);
setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(idleConnectionTestPeriod);
setLoginTimeout(seconds);
setMaxConnectionAge(maxConnectionAge);
setMaxIdleTime(maxIdleTime);
setTestConnectionOnCheckin(testConnectionOnCheckin);
setTestConnectionOnCheckout(testConnectionOnCheckout);
setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(unreturnedConnectionTimeout);
```

The issue I am trying to solve is with idle connections not being available after some time of inactivity, so on first usage after a long pause, my application is not able to connect to the database, and I get connection timeout after some time, but it is OK on the second usage.

Comment: you can get some idea from http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Comment: This was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of resources that provide documentation are:

[Instantiating and Configuring a ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_combopooleddatasource), specifically, for your list, the Appendix [Configuration Properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties) has almost all of the commands you are querying (including their defaults). The only one not specifically in the documentation was `LoginTimeout`.

Another resource is the JBoss Developer page [HowTo configure the C3P0 connection pool](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool?_sscc=t), which states:

> timeout Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 0
>   The seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire.

The page also includes an extract of the `hibernate.cfg.xml`